# javascript append while I click and hold the mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a simple "paint app" which appends one div while I click but it happens only once, now I want to append while I click and hold the mouse button just like a real paint thing but I've no idea how any ideas ?

```js
  $('#main').click(function(event){
    var mouseX = event.pageX;
    var mouseY = event.pageY;
    console.log(mouseX);
    $(this).append('<div class="smth" style="left:' + mouseX + 'px; top:' + mouseY + 'px"></div>');
  })
```

```html
        <div id="main">
          </div>
```

```css
#main{
  width:1000px;
  height:800px;
  border:2px solid black;
}
.smth{
  position: absolute;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background:red;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
}
```

Comment: Use `mousedown` to detect when the mouse is pressed, `mousemove` to detect movement, and `mouseup` when they let go.

Comment: why don't you use canvas for painting?